# Retrofit API to retrieve a png image

Tags: android, retrofit

Hi I am new to Retrofit framework for Android. I could get JSON responses from REST services using it but I don't know how to download a png using retrofit. I am trying to download the png from this url:
 http://wwwns.akamai.com/media_resources/globe_emea.png. 
What should be response Object to be specified in the Callback<> to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you need Retrofit to download the PNG. You could simply use normal I/O classes in Android.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As mentioned you shouldn't use Retrofit to actually download the image itself.  If your goal is to simply download the content without displaying it then you could simply use an Http client like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) which is another one of Square's libraries.

Here's a few lines of code which would have you download this image.  You could then read the data from the InputStream.

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://wwwns.akamai.com/media_resources/globe_emea.png")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            System.out.println("request failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            response.body().byteStream(); // Read the data from the stream
        }
    });
```

Even though Retrofit isn't the man for the job to answer your question, the signature of your Interface definition would like this.  But again don't do this.

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("/media_resources/{imageName}")
    void getImage(@Path("imageName") String imageName, Callback<Response> callback);
}
```

Comment: This is a more complicated approach using byteStream and not so much flexible as in Picasso (caching, resizing, cropping etc.).

Comment: The post mentions that this is an alternative only if you're just downloading content but aren't displaying it.  Pradeem's use case doesn't specifically specify that he wants to display the content.

Comment: btw why i shouldn't do that?

Answer (score 50):

Of course we usually use **Picasso** to load image, but sometimes we really need use **Retrofit** to load a special image (like fetch a captcha image), you need add some header for request, get some value from header of response (of course you can also use Picasso + OkHttp, but in a project you have already use Retrofit to handle most of  net requests), so here introduce how to implement by Retrofit 2.0.0 (I have already implemented in my project).

The key point is that you need use `okhttp3.ResponseBody` to receive response, else Retrofit will parse the response data as JSON, not binary data.

codes:

```
public interface Api {
    // don't need add 'Content-Type' header, it's useless
    // @Headers({"Content-Type: image/png"})
    @GET
    Call<ResponseBody> fetchCaptcha(@Url String url);
}

Call<ResponseBody> call = api.fetchCaptcha(url);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    // display the image data in a ImageView or save it
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                } else {
                    // TODO
                }
            } else {
                // TODO
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            // TODO
        }
    });
```

Comment: Call is from okhhtp3 or retrofit2?

Comment: @user2362956 , the call from retrofit2, but the retrofit2 depends or uses okhttp3 in the bottom layer.

Comment: I was looking for this answer for 2 hours, I owe you a beer! ;)

Comment: am getting this exception  D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null

Answer (score 20):

Declare it returning Call for instance:

```
@GET("/api/{api}/bla/image.png")
Call<ResponseBody> retrieveImageData();
```

then convert it to Bitmap yourself:

```
ResponseBody body = retrofitService.retrieveImageData().execute().body();
        byte[] bytes = body.bytes();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Comment: finally.......some one answered this. While using retrofit using bytestream to display the image won't work but when I used response.body().bytes() it worked perfectly fine.... Thanks @Alecio . I owe you alot...

Answer (score 16):

Retrofit is a REST library, you can use Retrofit only to get image URL but for displaying Image you should use Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting Picasso, it is very easy to use library.

Comment: but how to add headers while calling a url from picasso?

Answer (score 6):

### Details

- Android studio 3.1.4
- Kotlin 1.2.60
- Retrofit 2.4.0
- checked in minSdkVersion 19

### Solution

> object RetrofitImage

```
object RetrofitImage {

    private fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://google.com").build()
    }

    private interface API {
        @GET
        fun getImageData(@Url url: String): Call<ResponseBody>
    }

    private val api : API by lazy  { provideRetrofit().create(API::class.java) }

    fun getBitmapFrom(url: String, onComplete: (Bitmap?) -> Unit) {

        api.getImageData(url).enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<ResponseBody> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, t: Throwable?) {
                onComplete(null)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, response: Response<ResponseBody>?) {
                if (response == null || !response.isSuccessful || response.body() == null || response.errorBody() != null) {
                    onComplete(null)
                    return
                }
                val bytes = response.body()!!.bytes()
                onComplete(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### Usage 1

```
RetrofitImage.getBitmapFrom(ANY_URL_STRING) {
   // "it" - your bitmap
   print("$it")
}
```

### Usage 2

> Extension for ImageView

```
fun ImageView.setBitmapFrom(url: String) {
    val imageView = this
    RetrofitImage.getBitmapFrom(url) {
        val bitmap: Bitmap?
        bitmap = if (it != null) it else {
            // create empty bitmap
            val w = 1
            val h = 1
            val conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf)
        }

        Looper.getMainLooper().run {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap!!)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage of the extension**

```
imageView?.setBitmapFrom(ANY_URL_STRING)
```

Comment: @VarunRaj how did you detect lagging? Do you use this code in recycle view and it is laggy when you scroll it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this inside a recycler view. My recycler view is inside a nested scroll view it starts lagging as soon as images get in the screen

Comment: hm... it can be a problem. You will have to implement separate tasks queue for this actions (loading and rendering images). So, you just can't fun it without control on the main queue.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Retrofit to perform the `@GET` and just return the `Response`. Then in code you can do `isr = new BufferedInputStream(response.getBody().in())` to get the input stream of the image and write it into a Bitmap, say, by doing `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(isr)`.

Comment: Hi! i know its a quite old answer. I just wanted to add, that in retrofit 2.0 you have to return okhttp3.ResponseBody

Comment: why use new BufferedInputStream instead of just calling `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.getBody().in())`?

Comment: java.io.IOException: closed am getting this error with "SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null"

Answer (score 2):

I hope following code will help you:

Include following function inside `MainActivity.java`:

```
void getRetrofitImage() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitImageAPI service = retrofit.create(RetrofitImageAPI.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getImageDetails();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ResponseBody> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            try {

                Log.d("onResponse", "Response came from server");

                boolean FileDownloaded = DownloadImage(response.body());

                Log.d("onResponse", "Image is downloaded and saved ? " + FileDownloaded);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Following is the file handling code for image:

```
private boolean DownloadImage(ResponseBody body) {

        try {
            Log.d("DownloadImage", "Reading and writing file");
            InputStream in = null;
            FileOutputStream out = null;

            try {
                in = body.byteStream();
                out = new FileOutputStream(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "AndroidTutorialPoint.jpg");
                int c;

                while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                    out.write(c);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("DownloadImage",e.toString());
                return false;
            }
            finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            }

            int width, height;
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "AndroidTutorialPoint.jpg");
            width = 2*bMap.getWidth();
            height = 6*bMap.getHeight();
            Bitmap bMap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, width, height, false);
            image.setImageBitmap(bMap2);

            return true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DownloadImage",e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is done using Android Retrofit 2.0. I hope it helped you.

Source: [Image Download using Retrofit 2.0](http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/android-retrofit-2-0-tutorial-retrofit-android-example-download-image-url-display-android-device-screen/)

Answer (score 0):

***Easy & Best solution***

If API response is image, no need to use retrofit to fetch image. Using GlideUrl image can rendered easily with Glide

```
       val glideUrl = GlideUrl("APICall url",LazyHeaders.Builder()
                    .addHeader("X-Api-Key", "apiKey") // if any headers are required
                    .build())
       Glide.with(requireContext()).load(glideUrl).into(imageview)
```

Answer (score -1):

Retrofit is encoding your byte array to base 64. So decode your string and you are good to go. In this way you can retrieve a list of images.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapByEncodedString(String base64String) {
    String imageDataBytes = base64String.substring(base64String.indexOf(",")+1);
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
}
```