# How to get image from api response using Retrofit?

Tags: android, image, api, android-studio, retrofit2

As I am sending a  `GET` request using token to `API`, it responses only with **image**

For some reasons my Postman shows an **unreadable message**, but for another Postman on another PC returns an **image**

[image]
[image]

I don't know what I should write on Call response body to get image, as I mentioned with signs `???` below

```
@GET (api/profilephoto)
Call<???> getProfilePhoto (@Header("Authorization") String authToken);
```

> It is not just an url String, because it returns image using token only.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462523/retrofit-api-to-retrieve-a-png-image?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: have tried with String?