# Retrofit response body not parsing properly in android app

Tags: android, imageview, postman, retrofit2

I am receiving this response in postman 
in Android, my response.body() is not null but still, there is no image showing in the image view.

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    if (response.body()!=null) { 
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(response.body()).into(iv_userimage_header);
        Toast.makeText(SubtitutesDashboard.this, "Image Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is the response of postman

[image]

Comment: Your way is wrong. Because, you can't use `response.body()` method. You can use `response.body().byteStream()` method. Try this.

Comment: @MustafaYanık  Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(response.body().byteStream()).into(iv_userimage_header); Still no image is set

Comment: Ok. You can convert bytestream to Glide supported formats(uri, byte array etc.). Could you try this?

Comment: @MustafaYanık can you help a little more by telling me how?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use glide to load the url directly?

Comment: @IvanWooll I am not recieving url of image response is just a picture. You can see picture in question

Comment: Can you use log for response.body() in this method?

Comment: @MuratÇakır yes

Comment: So, did you see your image data log in console?

Comment: @MuratÇakır not yet

Comment: So it is not about load image or Glide. You should focus to your response for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out, make sure you get the callback for response using `okhttp3.ResponseBody`. So something like

```
...
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) { 
...
```

And then get your image as a bitmap using

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
```

You can set this bitmap directly to you `ImageView`

```
iv_userimage_header.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Or using Glide with `.asBitmap`

For more info refer [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25462523/retrofit-api-to-retrieve-a-png-image).