# How to display multiple images from a site in recyclerview kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I want to display images like this :

[image]

This site has well over 200 apps and i am trying to show their apps in my recycler view. I don't want to save them one by one but i couldn't find any documentation on how to pull image data from URL in Kotlin.

```
data class PostModel(
    val role : String = "listitem",
    val clazz : String = "Zc7IjY"
)
```

I tried getting their id numbers but failed.

I want to access the url below inside my main url. But not just for one image, i want to access it for all of the images.

```
@font-face {
    font-display: block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Montserrat Italic'), local('Montserrat-Italic'), 
    url("//static.parastorage.com/tag-bundler/api/v1/fonts-cache/googlefont/woff2/s/montserrat/v14/JTUQjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459WxRzS7m0dR9pBOi.woff2") format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
    }
```

Comment: Do they provide a list from a public API? If not you can't add the data..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is using a library like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/).

If you want to do it on your own you will have to decode the image yourself then transform it into a object that is accepted by an ImageView, you can refer to this other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/25463200/4632435